# Running content plugin on content prepare trigger for com_content attributes text

Tags: plugin, com-content, plugin-events

I created a custom plugin that allows the user to save custom text from a predefined list through editors buttons, in the attributes (attribs).

The idea was to give the users an easy way to add a few decorations and visual elements, by entering predefined "tagged" text, that triggers content plugins.

But echoing the attributes text bypasses the content plugins.

How to run the content plugins on the content prepare trigger for this text?

```
$attrbs = json_decode($this->item->attribs);
echo $attrbs->mygallery;
```

Comment: Similar question: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/12286/running-content-plugins-for-a-custom-editor-type-field-in-com-content?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Runnning content plugins on text for the content prepare trigger, you just need to call :

```
    echo JHtml::_('content.prepare',$attrbs->mygallery);
```