# Running content plugins for a custom editor type field in com_content

Tags: plugin, com-content, custom-field

For our latest Joomla-Projects, I extended the ***com_content*** component with custom fields using the following documentation:

https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_core_components_using_a_plugin

However, I did not use `params` as field name, but `attributes`, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form>
    <fields name="attribs" >
        <fieldset name="site1" label="Client Name">
            <field name.....
```

In the template, I can access these fields with ease:

```
$attr = json_decode($article->attribs);
```

Everything is working fine so far.

But, this method has one big downside. If I use other plugins/components for instance, galleries, that require shortcode inside the editor (such as: `{gallery id="2"}`), which gets replaced by the actual gallery when loading the page, it does not work.

The page simply shows the shortcode `{gallery id="2"}`, as the gallery content plugin does not parse the custom field (no plugin does...)

How can I enable the parsing by content-plugins for these fields?

Comment: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4177/running-content-plugin-on-content-prepare-trigger-for-com-content-attributes-tex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to echo the attrbs content through the `JHTML content.prepare`?

e.g.:

```
$attrbs = json_decode($this->item->attribs);

echo JHtml::_('content.prepare',$attrbs->myfield);
```